# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection on Masterpage

Tags: 2010, error, master-page

I have created a custom master based on [Just The Essentials.master by Heather Solomon](http://cdn.sharepointexperience.com/files/2011/09/Just_the_Essentials.master). When I apply it to a publising page it displays fine. When I go to edit mode I get the following:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index 

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +78
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +53
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiColumnValue.get_Item(Int32 index) +62
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.get_AssociatedContentTypeId() +153
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.get_AssociatedContentType() +75
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.get_UIDisplayName() +239
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayoutComparerByUIDisplayName.Compare(PageLayout x, PageLayout y) +20
   System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.SwapIfGreaterWithItems(T[] keys, IComparer`1 comparer, Int32 a, Int32 b) +153
   System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.QuickSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 right, IComparer`1 comparer) +186
   System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) +216

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.]
   System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) +10151111
   System.Array.Sort(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) +299
   System.Array.Sort(T[] array, IComparer`1 comparer) +86
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.GetAvailableCachedPageLayouts() +353
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.EditingMenuActions.PageLayoutAction.GetJsonPageLayoutsInfo() +105
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.EditingMenuActions.PageLayoutAction.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +275
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

If I could see the line it was pointing to in my code I could work it out. I guess I could be missing a control? How would you go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace, I'm more inclined to think that a control is being included that shouldn't be or that it is referring to a field that does not exist.  Look in your master page and page layout for a Publishing field and make sure that the field it mentions actually exists in the underlying list.  Remember to use the actual name of the field, not the display name.

I have not used Heather's master page as a starting point (though she normally does fantastic work) but have had great success with the [Starter Master page](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex

Comment: I tried swapping out the masterpage for the Randy's one (publishing and foundation) and I still get the error.

Comment: It looks like when I turn a custom feature on the publishing site it causes it to crash. Once it crashed it stays crashed even if the feature is turned off.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you use the default v4.master?  If the page layout used by the page is customized, you might want to check that as well.

Comment: I had a rogue featurew causing the issue. Deleting the feature fixed the problem.